Implementing Tensor ADT from Scratch Without Pytorch, Tensorflow or Any Such Library
I am working on a project for image recognition through convolutional neural networks, but the main assessment value of this project is implementing a new data type. I chose tensors for this task, but I find that there are resources only on using them through these libraries and I do not know how to start building from scratch like this. Help would be appreciated!
I have tried implementing through numpy arrays and the basic functions are easy enough, but the later convolution and pooling is troubling.

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
